# Will COMODO anti virus cover both OS in a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, antivirus

I have COMODO installed on the XP side of a dual boot with 12.04. I see partial answer in one posting, but my question was not entirely answered. When a scan is done on the windows partition, does it also scan the Ubuntu 12.04 partition?

Answer (score 4):

Windows can't access files on an ext4 partition which Ubuntu uses by default unless you install third party software on Windows to access files on ext4 partitions. For more information see [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) and [Does an ext4 writer for Windows exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/317240/does-an-ext4-writer-for-windows-exist).  Even if you took the trouble to install third party software to read/write ext4 in Windows, I still don't know if Comodo "likes" ext4. Comodo for Linux can read/write ext4, but I don't know if this functionality extends to Comodo for Windows, which is where you need Comodo the most. Google was not my friend this time when I tried to find out.

Another way to do it is to install ClamTK antivirus in Ubuntu from the Ubuntu Software Center. ClamTK can also scan files in Ubuntu for Windows malware. I am going to recommend doing it this way, because XP is unstable enough now that support for Windows XP has ended without complicating your XP system any further. If it works, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have clamTK installed on my Ubuntu machine, but I have windows 7 on another machine which I check with Windows defender.

However, another solution I use on both machines is to download the free Avira rescue system from

http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system

Although it is advertised as a scan and repair solution, it can also be used to regularly scan your system for threats and viruses. The rescue system comes as an iso image so you need to create a bootable CD from the image.

When used with Ubuntu or windows machine it first loads Linux then gives you an options menu.

During the boot process you are prompted for an internet connection and (if you give it access) automatically downloads the latest virus / malware definitions before it scans/repairs.

It seems to do a thorough job and since I started using it I have had no virus/malware problems at all on either machine. It also provides a useful registry editor.

However, I have not tried it with a dual boot Ubuntu/Windows machine but I don't see any reason why it should not work. It must be worth a try.

Comment: Avira Rescue System is based on Linux. It would truly amaze me, if it was unable to scan files on ext file systems.